# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /wp-content/themes/my-theme/header.php on line 277

Tags: php, wordpress

The code below is used to display a random banner image if you are on the page Services, or if you are of a child page of page id 1531, 1567 or 1533.

However, when I hit a page not found on a site I get the error mentioned in the title of this question above the banner image.

Below is the code being used

```
<?php

global $post;
$n = rand(1,7);

// error on the following line
if( is_page('Services') || $post->post_parent == 1531 || $post->post_parent == 1567 || $post->post_parent == 1533 ) : ?>
    <div class="banner-sub<?php echo ' banner' . $n; ?> rand"></div><!-- .banner -->
<?php else : ?>
    <div class="banner-sub overlay"></div><!-- .banner -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the 404 page, there is no post loaded, so `$post` is probably `null` which is a non-object, and has no properties such as `post_parent`.

You'll want to test for that:

```
if ( is_page('Services') || ( $post && ( $post->post_parent == 1531 || $post->post_parent == 1567 || $post->post_parent == 1533 ) ) ) : ?>
```

Comment: right, i added this and seems to have worked.:  
    global $post;
   <code> $n = rand(1,7);
    if ( !is_404() ) :
    if( is_page('Services') || $post->post_parent == 1531 || $post->post_parent == 1567 || $post->post_parent == 1533 ) : ?>
    <div class="banner-sub<?php echo ' banner' . $n; ?> rand"></div>
    <?php else : ?>
    <div class="banner-sub overlay"></div>
    <?php endif; ?> </code>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have access to the `$post` variable, you can find out when do you have access to it in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/170358/when-to-use-global-post-and-other-global-variables).

I also suggest using an array for the `post_parent` condition:

```
$excluded = [1531, 1533, 1567];

if (is_page('Services') || in_array($post->post_parent, $excluded)) {
    //
}
```